# Send TRUE/FALSE value with NSDictionary, but not with NSNumber class

Tags: ios, boolean, nsnumber

I have a web service that accepts a json response with boolean values in the true/false format.

When I use the `[NSNumber numberWithBool:]` I read in my `NSDictionary` the 0/1 value.

I cannot manage to transform the 0/1 values to true/false. Does someone have a clue on how to do it?

I am using the [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) library to transform the values from the dictionary.

Thanks.

[EDIT 1]
when I use
`[notifications setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[thisUser notifyYourActivity]] forKey:@"profile_activity"]`

I have the 0/1 value. I need the TRUE/FALSE not the 0/1 value

Comment: Sorry but can you include your actual code because I'm a little confused at what you are doing? If you pass in a bool into `numberWithBool:` then it will return you a number what else are you expecting it to return?

Comment: Try it with NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: Add some more code, I have looked into JSONKit code and if I understand `[NSNumber numberWithBool:]` correctly, then your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Integers, floating point numbers, and booleans will all return an object of class NSNumber. If you use the boolValue property, you will get the correct result if your JSON data was true or false. You will also get YES or NO if the JSON data was an integer or floating point number with a non-zero or zero value.

If you want to know whether a value was true and not for example 1, or if it was false and not for example 0, the easiest way is to check

```
if (result == @YES) -> true
if (result == @NO) -> false
```

kCFBooleanTrue and kCFBooleanFalse are the same pointers, and so are [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] and [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO].

And yes, I'm comparing the pointers and not the values. MacOS X or iOS only ever creates one NSNumber for boolean true and one for boolean false.

Comment: The problem is that if, say, a JSON serializer simply examines the object type and determines it's an NSNumber it may just output `1` or `0` rather than `true` or `false`.  The serializer needs to query the inner details of the NSNumber (there's a way, but I forget at the moment) to see whether it originated as a number or a Boolean value.  It can get a little messy.